# How to install a security certifcates on Window CE < 5.0 not through UI?

Tags: security, certificate, windows-ce, x509certificate, digital-certificate

I would like to install EAP-TLS & WPA2 certificates on a Windows CE 5.0 platform.
I can succesfully import them through the Control Panel -> Certificates method but would like this done on coldboot of the device.
Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could only be done by using the RF client firmware Fusion 2.57 version and above. The certificates need to be placed in the Application\UserCerts and Application\RootCerts.